# rails s command not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello I am working with ruby on rails on a windows 8 machine and I am having a hard time setting up ruby 2.1 on my machine.  when I run rails s I get the following error:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.2.0/lib/execjs/run
times.rb:51:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://gi
thub.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUn
available)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.2.0/l
ib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/execjs-2.2.0/l
ib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.5.1
/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/uglifier-2.5.1
/lib/uglifier.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/
lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/
lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
        from C:/HandCo-op/HandCo-op/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>
'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.2
.rc1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.2
.rc1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:79:in `block in server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.2
.rc1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.2
.rc1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.2
.rc1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.1.2
.rc1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

I think this is because I need ruby 2.1 and the version installed is 2.0.  Does anyone know what I should do to fix these errors?  Thanks a lot anyone who has an idea on why I can not run rails s.

Comment: Protip, the stack traces usually give a clue to why, or at least where the problem is. Though the first line is pretty cryptic, the next points you to https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for more information.

Answer (score 2):

It's funny, I had just initialized a new rails 4 project with ruby 2.1 and when forgetting to update the `Gemfile` I got the exact error message a few minutes ago.

Update your `Gemfile` uncommenting the `gem 'therubyracer'` line, so it looks like:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby
```

Run the `bundle` command after updating the `Gemfile`.

The error message is because you don't have a runtime installed.

**Update: Options on Windows**

I've had success installing and using `closure-compiler` gem on Windows 7+ x64 arch.  My development box switches from linux to windows from time to time so following is how I have my `Gemfile` setup:

```
# Gemfile

gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
gem 'execjs', :platforms => :ruby

gem 'closure-compiler'
```

And update your configuration for either of your environments in `config/environments/` or app wide in `config/application.rb` by updating the following line:

```
config.assets.js_compressor = :closure
```

Please see [Customizing the Pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#customizing-the-pipeline) for further information at RailsGuide.

Comment: I tried that and got the same error.  however after un-commenting that line and running bundle install I do not see therubyracer being installed.

Comment: @ZachyBear, please see the update.  Hope that helps!